# Get the number of posts from a certain category including trashed

Tags: php, wordpress, count, categories

I'm able to get the number of published posts on a specific category (3) like this:

```
<?php
$theID = 3;
$postsInCat = get_term_by('id','' . $theID . '','category');
$postsInCat = $postsInCat->count;
echo $postsInCat . " posts in this category";
?>
```

But what I also now need to do in a separate statement is get the number of just trashed posts for a specific category (3).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be your solution is : remember category id is saved in wp_terms table,,from that u can get it.and post type is 'post' thx

```
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'no_found_rows'  => true,
        'post_status'    => 'trash',
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'category'       => 3 ); 
    $post=get_posts($args);
    print_r($post);
    echo "<br><br>Total Trashed :";
    echo $total = ( $post ) ? count( $post ) : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do all this is one query using `get_posts` as an alternative

**The concept**

Retrieve all posts from the specified category with the post status `trash` or `publish`

Next you need to break up the returned array into two arrays, one for `trash`ed posts and one for `publish`ed posts. Make use the `post_status` object to sort posts according to post status

You can now just do a count on the two arrays and echo the post count

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status'    => array( 'trash', 'publish' ),
    'category'       3
); 
$posts = get_posts($args);

if( $posts ) {

    $trash = [];
    $publish = [];
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        if( $post->post_status == 'trash' ) {
            $trash[] = $post;
        }else{
            $publish[] = $post;
        }
    }

    echo 'There are ' . count($trash) . ' trashed posts </br>';
    echo 'There are ' . count($publish) . ' published posts';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_posts()` and count the results.

```
// Get trashed post in category 3.
$trashed_posts = get_posts( array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'no_found_rows'  => true,
    'post_status'    => trash,
    'cat'            => 3,
) );

// If posts were found count them else set count to 0.
$trashed_count = ( $trashed_posts ) ? count( $trashed_posts ) : 0;
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks like it should work, but I'm getting an error that I can't see what it's happening:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)`

Occurs on this line:

`'posts_per_page' => -1,`

Comment: My mistake. I'd missed the array. Please retry